# Android Textview Truncate

Tags: android, fade, truncate

I have a textview that have a maxline of 2. 
When i put this code

```
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

result will be 
line1 
line2 bla bla bla b...

but when I use

```
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

nothing is changed

my expected result on marquee is the fading effect that looks something like this

[image]

So any idea on how to achieve this fade effect on textview with multiple line

Comment: you need an animation or just fade?

Comment: Have you try setting the attribute `android:lines="2"`? Maybe forcing your `TextView` to have 2 lines will do the work for you for the second line.

Comment: @RedaM actually no. my textview is actually expandable. ill try setting it

Comment: @RedaM unfortunately still the same result on marquee. no change at all

Answer (score 0):

Style the text alpha property using the Android text library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).